# How can I switch WordPress to mobile theme (with link to full site)

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I'm building a website in WordPress which has a separate mobile theme (this obviously uses the same database as the main site). The mobile theme is a child of the main theme, to maximize code reuse.

I downloaded a mobile detection script that works pretty well, but I can't figure out how to switch to the mobile theme only for the current user, with an option to link to the full website.

I don't want to create a multisite for this - it seems like an overkill (and there's the duplicate content issue).

I tried two ways:

- themeswitch: Redirect to `http://example.com/?theme=mobile_theme` - not working
- a weird solution I found somewhere on the web:

  ```
  add_filter( 'template', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );   
  add_filter( 'option_template', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );  
  add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'wpse_49223_change_theme' );

  function wpse_49223_change_theme($theme) 
  {
      include 'script/Mobile_Detect.php';
      $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
      if ( $detect->isMobile() )
          $theme = 'pinnacle_mobile';
      return $theme;
  }
  ```

This is not working either.

Does anyone have a working solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed to use the Theme Switch plug-in.

There are two things of importance here:

- Set "Who can switch themes" to "everybody"
- redirect to http://website.com/?theme=Mobile+Theme

Note that the theme parameter has to be the **actual theme name**, not the directory name. It's **case sensitive** and uses **`+`** instead of spaces.

Comment: This solution did not work on the live server though, only on localhost. I had to use a WP plug-in called 'Mobile Smart'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if applicable for your site. But one common solution to this is media queries.

http://cssmediaqueries.com/

Basically its ***if "mobile device" show this css else show "normal css"***

Another idea is to **redirect to **mobile.yourdomain.com****  when a mobile user connects.  And having your mobile wordpress theme on that domain.

Comment: Media queries are not applicable here, as the layout and scripts are quite different for mobiles.